# Time difference of 14 digit date YYYYmmDDHHMMSS

Tags: unix

I need a Unix script which i can find the time difference between 2 times look like  YYYYmmDDHHMMSS

Example

T1=20120624192555

T2=20120624204006

So the time difference will be =1:14:11

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can get around specifying the date format, but here is a rather lengthy `date` solution:

```
# Get seconds since epoch
D1=$(date --date "${T1:0:4}-${T1:4:2}-${T1:6:2} ${T1:8:2}:${T1:10:2}: ${T1:12:2}" +%s)
D2=$(date --date "${T2:0:4}-${T2:4:2}-${T2:6:2} ${T2:8:2}:${T2:10:2}: ${T2:12:2}" +%s)

date --date "0 + $(( D2 - D1 )) seconds" +%T
```

See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for the ${VAR:OFF:LEN} reference.

Note: as mentioned by *jrouquie* below, this fails when exceeding 24 hours. This is a limitation of the `date` command, $(( D2 - D1 )) still gives the correct result in seconds though.

Comment: @waseemasaad, what kind of input range do you expect? The "+%T' is elegant if T1 and T2 are guaranteed not to be more than 24h appart, but if there is more than one day difference, this script have incorrect output. This is why in my application I had to resort to the "manual" expr and modulo.

Answer (score 0):

```
time1=`echo $1 | sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'`
time2=`echo $2 | sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'`

seconds1=`date --utc -d "$time1" +%s`
seconds2=`date --utc -d "$time2" +%s`
difference=`expr $seconds2 - $seconds1`

echo `expr $difference / 3600`:`expr "(" $difference / 60 ")" % 60`:`expr $difference % 60`
```

Note the use of `--utc` which prevents a bug with daylight saving time.

Caveats:

This script does not check input.

It assumes $2 > $1.

It could be rewritten to factor repeated code

**EDIT**: regarding the first comment, here is a version without the "-r" option to sed (-r means --regexp-extended, which here allowed to dispense with all the backslashes).

```
time1=`echo $1 | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'`
time2=`echo $2 | sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/'`

seconds1=`date --utc -d "$time1" +%s`
seconds2=`date --utc -d "$time2" +%s`
difference=`expr $seconds2 - $seconds1`

echo `expr $difference / 3600`:`expr "(" $difference / 60 ")" % 60`:`expr $difference % 60`
```

Comment: hey there im sorry i get the below error   sed: illegal option -- r

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution taking the best of the one by Thor/kjp and mine:

```
#!/bin/bash
function seconds_since_epoch() {
    echo $(date --utc --date "${1:0:4}-${1:4:2}-${1:6:2}
                              ${1:8:2}:${1:10:2}:${1:12:2}" +%s)
}
difference=$(( `seconds_since_epoch $2` - `seconds_since_epoch $1` ))
echo \
`expr $difference / 3600`:\
`expr "(" $difference / 60 ")" % 60`:\
`expr $difference % 60`
```

Comment: what is function seconds since epoch()